# Segmentation fault in visual studio cmake remote linux develop mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

I am developing a mysql project with visual studio cmake remote linux.

My version is vs2017,cmake 3.8(by vs installer install),mysql 8.0.18,mysql connector c++ 8.0,boost_1_64_0,

and my linux os is centos 8.

First I test the code in Windows-debug in vs,it's run successfully,

then I link my VMWave centos8,error happended.

```
con = driver->connect(host.c_str(), user.c_str(), password.c_str());
```

Vs tell me **Segmentation fault** in thie line.

There are my cmakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

IF(WIN32)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/include")
ENDIF(WIN32)

IF(UNIX)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/include")
ENDIF(UNIX)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF(Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
ENDIF(Boost_FOUND)

IF(WIN32)
    LINK_DIRECTORIES("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0/lib64/vs14")
    LINK_DIRECTORIES("C:/Program Files/MySQL/mysql-8.0.18-winx64/lib")
ENDIF(WIN32)

IF(UNIX)
    LINK_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++/lib64")
    LINK_DIRECTORIES("/usr/local/mysql/lib")
ENDIF(UNIX)

add_executable (CMakeLinkLinux "CMakeLinkLinux.cpp" "CMakeLinkLinux.h")

IF(WIN32)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(CMakeLinkLinux mysqlcppconn.dll libmysql.dll)
ENDIF(WIN32)

IF(UNIX)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(CMakeLinkLinux libmysqlcppconn.so libmysqlclient.so)
ENDIF(UNIX)
```

main.cpp

```
#include "CMakeLinkLinux.h"
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    mutex mtx;
    int flag;
    cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver=NULL;
        sql::Connection *con=NULL;
        sql::Statement *stmt=NULL;
        sql::ResultSet *res=NULL;
        //tcp://192.168.248.128:3306
        string host = "tcp://192.168.248.128:3306";
        string user = "root";
        string password = "123";
        string database = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA";
        mtx.lock();
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        if (!driver) {
            cout << "driver error" << endl;
        }
        mtx.unlock();
        driver->threadInit();
        cout << "connecting......mysql" << endl;
        con = driver->connect(host.c_str(), user.c_str(), password.c_str());
        cout << "connected successfully" << endl;
        con->setSchema(database);
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,CREATE_OPTIONS FROM TABLES WHERE CREATE_OPTIONS LIKE '%ENCRYPTION%'");
        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "TABLE_SCHEMA:";
            cout << res->getString("TABLE_SCHEMA").c_str() << endl;
            cout << "TABLE_NAME:";
            cout << res->getString("TABLE_NAME").c_str() << endl;
            cout << "CREATE_OPTIONS:";
            cout << res->getString("CREATE_OPTIONS").c_str() << endl;
        }

        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;
        driver->threadEnd();
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException&e) {
        cout << "#ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line" << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "#ERR:" << e.what();
        cout << "(MySQL error code:" << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ",SQLState:" << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl;
        cout << "link failed" << endl;
    }

    cin >> flag;
    return 0;
}
```

**I find ans by google and many ways,I didn't know why Segmentation fault in my code,someone tell lock the driver code can run in stackoverflow,but I still Segmentation fault in my code.**

Update:

gdb output:

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at /var/tmp/src/2d31707c-c3da-e131-91d2-9c506bc1ae02/Linux-Debug/CMakeLinkLinux/CMakeLinkLinux.cpp:9
9       cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5f9ae88 in __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: what is the value of `con` if `con = driver->connect(host.c_str(), user.c_str(), password.c_str());` fails?

Comment: I update my gdb output,I don't know what is fails value,
`
driver->connect
`
the fail lead to link mysql?